# MOSFETS and high impedance output

Tags: mosfet

[image]

In this circuit, for which value of CLK will the output **Y** be high-Z?

Is CLK=0 right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output will be high-Z in 2 cases:

1) When CLK=0 and D=1

2) When CLK=1 and D=0

If you want high-Z for both values of D you need to feed different values for CLK and notCLK inputs.